# Giving Google API key in Google street map used by Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, google-maps

I using google map as tilelayer in leaflet and its working good but i know after free view ends google will stop displaying of its map

```
       googleHybrid = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
maxZoom: 20,
subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

Does anybody know where to put API key or is it free to use?

Answer (score 1):

you can add below piece of code in your code

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&libraries=places">
    </script>
```

Comment: can i know how google knows i how many view my map have....since from 10 days m not providing any key....

Comment: visit (https://console.developers.google.com/)

Comment: how adding this in makes the url in question legal?